# Does Java ellipsis cause memory allocation of an array behind the scenes?

Tags: java

I am writing an Android game, where I make sure there are no memory allocations going on. Everything is pooled.

In one of my helper functions I want to use ellipsis.
Does Java ellipsis cause memory allocation of an array behind the scenes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the caller. If the caller provides individual values, the compiler changes that calling code to create an array behind the scenes. If they provide an array directly, there's no need for a new one.

For example:

```
public void foo(String... names) {
}

public void bar1() {
    // Does allocate array on each call
    foo("x", "y", "z");
}

private static final String[] EXISTING_ARRAY = new String[10];

public void bar2() {
    // No allocation
    foo(EXISTING_ARRAY);
}
```

So if you want every array creation to be really obvious in the calling code, using varargs would be a a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Java ellipsis cause memory allocation of an array behind the scenes?

Yes, except in the case where you are passing an array of the correct type as the last parameter; e.g.

```
public void helper(int ... args) {
    // ...
}

int[] intArray = ...
helper(intArray);  // no allocation performed here

helper(1, 2, 3);   // allocation performed here
```

(But if you are always going to pass an explicit array to avoid the allocation, there's little point declaring the method with variable arity syntax.)

The JLS ([8.4.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.1)) says this:

> "If the last formal parameter is a variable arity parameter of type T, it is considered to define a formal parameter of type T[]. ... All the actual argument expressions that do not correspond to the formal parameters preceding the variable arity parameter will be evaluated **and the results stored into an array** that will be passed to the method invocation."

(Emphasis added)

Comment: I think a blanket "yes" is a little bit strong. It's entirely feasible to write code which calls a varargs method without allocating an array.